# Что за обращение через "class"

Tags: java, классы, javafx

Я тут начал изучать `JavaFx`, и наткнулся на такой кусок кода

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
```

Хотел бы узнать что это за обращение `.class` ?

Comment: Тут написано, что надо найти путь к файлу HelloApplication и в аналогичной ресурсной папке поискать файл hello-view.fxml. Например у вас package ru.upiter.april.HelloApplication. Эта строка будет искать /ru/upiter/april/hello-view.fxml

Comment: @Maxim может быть, оформите как ответ?

Comment: @Maxim спасибо за ответ! И может вы можете дать сслыку на описание этого в документации, или  какую-нибудь статью?

Comment: @Зонтик не, я уже несколько раз такое оформлял, еще раз не хочется.

Comment: @Upiter1401 Можно открыть javadoc на методе getResource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Примечание от автора: этот ответ взят из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1516029/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-class#comment2721842_1516029) @Maxim, поэтому был сделан [общим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki). [Подробнее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3069/532877).

Это означает, что нужно найти путь к файлу `HelloApplication` и в аналогичной ресурсной папке поискать файл `hello-view.fxml`. Например, у вас `package ru.upiter.april.HelloApplication`. Эта строка будет искать `/ru/upiter/april/hello-view.fxml`

[Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).